# Closure of $ \{n\} $ in $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$, with the topology $U_k=\{n: n\mid k, n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2} \}$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$

Tags: general-topology

> For the set of integers $ \geq 2 $, define topology to be $ U_k=\{n: n|k, n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2} \} $ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2} $ and their unions. Then what is the closure of $ \{n\} $?

My attempt: In order to find the closure of $ \{ n \} $, we need to find all the limit points of $ \{ n \} $, i.e. $$ x\in\overline{\{ n \}}\longleftrightarrow \text{$ \forall $ open set $ U $ containing $ x $}, U\cap\{ n \}\neq\emptyset. $$

The set $ \{ sn: s\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} \} $ satisfies the condition;

For every point $ y \in \{ sn:s\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} \}^{C} $, we can always find an open set $ U_{y} $ not containging $ n $.

So we conclude that $ \overline{\{ n \}}=\{ sn: s\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} \} $.

> Question: Is my solution right? I am also looking for different approaches. Thanks~

Comment: Up to now, your proof only shows that the closure of $\{ n \}$ is **at most** the set that you found. You still need to show that the set is really a subset of the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that

$$\overline{\{n\}} = \{ln: l \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}\}$$

The right to left is clear: if we have $ln$ in some open set $U_k$ then $ln$ divides $k$, so $n$ divides $k$ and so $U_k \cap \{n\} \neq \emptyset$. As this holds for all open sets $U_k$, $ln \in \overline{\{n\}}$.
Reversely, if $m$ is not a multiple of $n$, then $U_m$ is a neighbourhood of $m$ ($m | m$), that does not contain $n$ as $n$ does not divide $m$ (and $U_m$ contains only the divisors of $m$). So $m \notin \overline{\{n\}}$. This shows the equality.